# angularJS ng-repeat issue - adding a function to the $scope

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using AJAX to get data from a json file, add it to the controller $scope and then use it in ng-repeat. All works fine until I try adding a function to the $scope so it will do another fucntion. 
Working OK:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('CouponsApp',[]);

    myApp.controller("CouponController",function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('CouponsJSON.json').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.CouponsList = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log((data || 'Coupons AJAX Req Failed') + ': ' + status);
        });

});
```

ng-repeat stops going over my json and not displaying in my html:

```
var myApp = angular.module('CouponsApp',[]);

myApp.controller("CouponController",function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('CouponsJSON.json').
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.CouponsList = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log((data || 'Coupons AJAX Req Failed') + ': ' + status);
        });
    $scope.doStuff()
    {
        var cellMarkerArray = [];
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.CouponsList.CellPhones.length;i++)
        {
            cellMarkerArray = $scope.CouponsList.CellPhones[i].localVendorAddress;
        }
    };
});
```

Any idea? 
The point is to add table rows in ng-repeat and it works, but I need an option to press a button and run a function. It doesn't have to be a part of the $scope, but it needs values from one of the table data tags?

Answer (score 1):

$scope.doStuff should be a function.

```
$scope.doStuff = function()
    {
        var cellMarkerArray = [];
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.CouponsList.CellPhones.length;i++)
        {
            cellMarkerArray = $scope.CouponsList.CellPhones[i].localVendorAddress;
        }
    };
```